# django csrf error on HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django

I know some people are going to think this is a duplicate, but I have spent all afternoon on Stack Overflow looking for the answer..
I have a page with a list of items, with, for each of them, a button which I would like to trigger a small update in the database. I don't know if this has any bearing, but the html file containing the button is included:

```
{% include "accueil/impasse.html" with l=l only %}
```

the file "impasse.html" itself is:

```
<a {% if l.impasse %} class="impasse" {% endif %} href="{% url "index" %}lecon/{{l.numero}}"> {{l.numero}} : {{l.titre}} </a>
{% if l.impasse %}
    {% include "accueil/boutonDesImpasse.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% include "accueil/boutonImpasse.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

and the file "accueil/boutonImpasse" which is the one that triggers the error is:

```
<form action="{% url "index" %}lecon/{{l.numero}}/impasse" method="post">
{% csrf_token %} 
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Je fais l'impasse sur cette leçon</button>
</div>
</form>
```

The corresponding view is:

```
@login_required()
def impasse(request,numero):
id = numeroAId(numero)
if id==None:
     return HttpResponse("Erreur, cette leçon n'existe pas.")
else:
     imp = Impasse(user=request.user,lecon=id)
     imp.save()
     return HttpResponseRedirect('/lecon',context_instance=RequestContext(context))
```

Now, at this point, I have a CSRF error (in the else branch). I know that many people with the same type of error were advised to use render_to_response with the corresponding template, but I can't, because the view "lecon" associated with the url "lecon" does complicated things before throwing the page, so what I really want is to load the view "lecon". Note that after I get the error, if I try again the url that failed, it loads as wanted. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with render_to_response, or the redirect.

You are specifically excluding the csrf token variable from the context of the excluded templates by using "only" in the include tag. Don't do that.

(And HttpResponseRedirect doesn't take a context_instance parameter, so no idea what you are doing there.)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, that of course makes perfect sense! I don't remember why I had to put that there in the first place. As for the context_instance, that was an attempt to force acknowledgement of the csrf token by mimicking what was suggested on SO.